# how to completly remove # tag from angular route?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache, nginx, url-rewriting

i am using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` to hiding # tag in addressbar.

```
angular.module('witnessApp',['ngRoute','witnessApp.Service','witnessApp.Controller','ui.bootstrap','ngAnimate','ngTouch','growlNotifications', 'ngSanitize'])
  .config(function ($routeProvider,$provide,$locationProvider) {
  var loginReq;
    $routeProvider
     .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller:'LoginCtrl',
        access: { "requiredLogin": false }
      })
     .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/login'
      })
     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  })
```

when app started it redirect to (login page) localhost:3000/login(it remove # sign from localhost:3000/#/login) but when i manually type or hit localhost:3000/login it does not redirect to login page. because it does api call using this. why it is not redirect to login?
how can i completly remove # tag from angular? i dont need # in angular route even if i hit url manually.is there any alternative to resolve this issue?

Edited:-

i am using express framework at backend.
code for server.js :

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = module.exports = express();

app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);

app.set('views', __dirname + "/views");

app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
console.log('[Application] on port 3000');
```

some guys(which is commented below) suggest to handle this route in backend.but i dont have any idea.could you please suggest me how to do this?

Comment: if `/login` is going to your api, you probably need to move your api to another path, such as `/api/*` so that you can rewrite everything that isn't `/api/*` to `/index.html`

Comment: you would need server side configuration which hands over routing responsibility to client. so server should always route to / or load index.html by default and from there on only client should take care of routing

Comment: which web server are you using? nginx? Apache?

Comment: i am using Apache server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### With Server Side Language/Routing

Are you using any server side languages/frameworks to route your application (like PHP/Laravel or Node/Express)?

Like one of the other answers states, you will have to create a catch-all route so that any routes that aren't specifically routed server-side will be passed to Angular for routing. I can help out with the catch-all route if you let me know the setup you are using.

#### Node/Express Routing

When using Node and Express, you have to define a **catch-all** route. Currently you have the `/` route for your home page, but your server won't know what to do with `/login`. Use the route `*` to route all unspecified requests to that index file and your Angular app. Here is the route you need:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});
```

Also, note that if you want to have API routes like you stated earlier, they should be defined **above** the catch-all route if you want them to work.

[Here](http://scotch.io/bar-talk/setting-up-a-mean-stack-single-page-application) are some [MEAN](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular) tutorials to reference. *Full Disclosure:* I wrote those articles.

### Without Server Side Language/Routing (All Angular)

If you aren't using any server-side languages and just have the Angular app loading right from the beginning, maybe try adding `<base href="/">` to the head of your document like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <base href="/">
</head>
```

This lets your application know that the root of your document is `/` and will route it accordingly. So your application will know where `/login` will be. Further Reading: [Relative Angular Links](http://scotch.io/quick-tips/js/angular/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag#setting-%3Cbase%3E-for-relative-links)

**Edit:** Updating for Node/Express catch-all route to route things to Angular

Comment: i am using express framework at server side.could you please guide me to resolve this issue? i have added server.js code in my question.

Comment: I've updated the answer to add the route you need. Just a quick route change and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the configuration of your web server so that it redirects any unknown URL to index.html or whatever your main AngularJS HTML file is.